# How can I change the mouse sensitivity?

Tags: pc, xcom-enemy-unknown

Is it possible to adjust the mouse sensitivity in the PC version of XCOM: Enemy Unknown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently yes, but for some reason there's no UI for this.

Go to the Steam folder (usually `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\`), and then navigate down to `XCom-Enemy-Unknown\Engine\Config`.

Open up `BaseInput.ini` in your favourite text editor and adjust the `MouseSensitivity` value to whatever you find most comfortable. This line should appear right near the top of the file.

It looks like lower values result in a faster mouse movement, but I'm not sure on the exact scale. I'm currently running with -60.0 and it seems pretty good to me. The setting also seems to only apply to the game itself and doesn't affect the main menu.